# Gitlab CICD - Run a mvn clean install before building a docker container

Tags: maven, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, centos7

We are running a spring-boot application that requires you to run a `mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true` before you can run a `docker build`. Is there any images with both maven and docker installed?

I have tried running a before script with a maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-slim image then specifying a separate image in the job.

```
image: maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-slim

before_script:
      - mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

build_archivist_elasticsearch:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  script:
    - cd archivist
    - docker build -t xxxx/xxxxx:development
```

Need the `mvn clean install` to build and create the artifacts then run the `docker build -t` and `docker push` to our repo.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to utilize artifacts in the gitlab-ci.yml file to store the dependencies needed for the docker build (ie. *.jar and *.zip files)

```
image: docker:latest
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build_artifacts:
  image: maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-slim
  stage: build
  script:
      - mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - archivist/target/*.jar
      - elasticsearch/*.zip

build_archivist_elasticsearch:
  stage: deploy
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay
  script:
    - cd archivist
    - docker build -t xxxxx/xxxxxx:development .
```

`

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#artifacts

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problem to build spring boot image using spotify [docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin)

Here is our final configuration :

```
stages:
  - build

variables:
  MVN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=/cache/maven.repository"

build:
  image: maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-slim
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MVN_OPTS clean test -Duser.timezone=CET
  tags:
    - docker
```

With `docker` tags, we select a kubernetes gitlab-runner configured to trigger containers based on `docker:latest`